# How to implement a callback to Java from C using JNI?

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface

I use JNI in my Java code to call native C code. This works fine and I'm doing some processing in the C code. The C code registers an event listener so that I'm notified every time a new result is ready in the C part.

Now I want to return the results to the Java code like that:

```
void notifyGazeEvent()
{
    jclass cls = (*env)->GetObjectClass(env, obj);
    jmethodID mid = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, cls, "newGazeEvent", "(I)V");
    if (mid == 0)
    {
        return; 
    }
    printf("In C, about to enter Java");
    (*env)->CallVoidMethod(env, obj, mid, 1);
}
```

The problem now is: I don't know where to get the JNIEnv object and the jObject object from. This is passed when I first call the C code:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
Java_a_b_C_doCalculation(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj)
{
// here I register all the handlers etc, 
}
```

But I don't know how I can pass the references until my method that does the callback to Java.

Comment: You could check out [JavaCPP - Creating Callbacks Functions](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacpp#creating-callback-functions) for that. It would save you a lot of trouble.

Answer (score 1):

To keep the `jobject obj` outside the `Java_a_b_C_doCalculation` function, you have to create a global reference, since all objects (JNIEnv also) are no longer valid after the function returns. A global reference can easily be created with [`NewGlobalRef`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#NewGlobalRef).

The `JNIEnv` pointer can't be saved that way, also if the thread that calls `notifyGazeEvent()` was created in C you have to attach the thread to the JVM first. Save the `JavaVM *vm` pointer from [`JNI_OnLoad`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/invocation.html#JNJI_OnLoad), and either optain the JNIEnv with [`GetEnv`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/invocation.html#GetEnv) or attach a newly created thread with [AttachCurrentThread *(AsDaemon)*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/invocation.html#AttachCurrentThread).